# Download or Save a Binary PDF Data to a local drive

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I am working with a client who uses a webservice and SOAP for making requests. I have Node-Express application and to do a request I am using the [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) node module which returns me an object with a property having a binary data. The data looks something like this :

> JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2Jq\n CjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL091dGxpbmVzCi9Db3VudCAwCj4+CmVuZG9iagozIDAgb2JqCjw8\n Ci9UeXBlIC9QYWdlcwovQ291bnQgNAovS2lkcyBbMTggMCBSIDE5IDAgUiAyMCAwIFIgMjEgMCBS\n .... .... ....

As you can see, there are \n after a fixed length.

How can I convert the above Binary data into a PDF and download it. Our client says it has all the required data that is needed to convert to a PDF and download it.
I tried using fs.writeFile() to write it to a folder, but when I try to open that file it says the file is corrupted. Here's a code snippet :

```js
soapClient.MyFunction(arguments, function(err, result){
  if(err) throw err;
  if(result){
    console.log(result.data) //... Has the Binary data JVBERi0xLjQK....

    fs.writeFile('./output.pdf', result.data, {encoding : 'binary'},       function(res){
          console.log('File saved!');
        })
  }
})
```

Can anybody help me out here? I know it sounds stupid. Searched for a lot of blogs, couldn't find the right one. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: If the content of the pdf is not private, it would be nice to have a full sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after all the search and twists and turn, finally was able to write the file :

`fs.writeFile('./public/output.pdf', new Buffer(result.data, "base64"), 
    function(response){
        console.log('File Saved!');
});`

Answer (score 0):

I would first try differents encodings with a simple html page by copy pasting the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQK....">Download Base64</a>
        <a href="data:application/pdf;binary,JVBERi0xLjQK....">Download Binary</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Why not also trying with and without the **/n** as you noticed.

Then when you'll be able to open the file we can see how to automatise the process.

Something coming back in my mind is that IE had troubles with pdf MIME type, try with **application/octet-stream** as well.

Comment: Ok, I was able to finally write the file. It is very simple :
`fs.writeFile('./public/output.pdf', new Buffer(result.data, "base64"), function(response){
                                            console.log('File Saved!');
                                        });`